# Database engine for a (big) Python project

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, performance

I have a huge project written in PHP and the data is stored in MySQL (mostly MyISAM tables and a bit of InnoDB). Because the project gets bigger and more complicated I want to rewrite it using object oriented programming and in Python. What choice of database engines do I have in Python? What DBs are mostly used for large Python projects (ca. 500 simultaneous and active users on the website)?

Comment: Why don't you just connect your python code to your existing MySQL servers.  You know that those can handle the load.  The python db adapters aren't going to make any significant performance problems for any modern database, so just connect up to what you already have and be done with it.

Comment: 500 users is not really "big".

Comment: Postgresql is pretty popular with Python people.

Comment: I wouldn't try to put you off switching to Python, but if the project is huge, would it not be easier to optimise your PHP site?

Comment: If it's legacy PHP code that would most likely be a full rewrite, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think PostgreSQL is most common in the python world with MySQL close behind. However, it doesn't really matter - the [python database api](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) is the same with only minor differences between database engines (mainly the placeholder for values - it might be `?` or `%s` etc.).

However, consider using SQLAlchemy - either just for SQL abstraction or its ORM which is pretty awesome. And either way, unless you want to use database-engine-specific things you can use *any* database - be it sqlite, mysql, pgsql, oracle or anything else supported by SQLAlchemy.

Even though you might be using something completely different, just in case you use [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) as your web framework (you *do* plan to use a WSGI framework, right?!), there is [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) which makes it extremely easy to get started with it.
In case you are going to use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) it already comes with its own ORM.